# How to change navigation header color in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, android-statusbar

How do I change the color of the navigation header in a React Native app?

I tried initialising background color but it didn't work.

Below is my code snippet for `navigationOptions`:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    header: props => <Header 
        navigation={navigation}
        title={'Dashboard'}
        toggleDrawer
    />
})
```

Also, is it possible to set status bar color?

Comment: Since you're providing a `custom header`, you need to change the styles there.

Comment: It is not getting changed in Custom header @PritishVaidya

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change it with `headerStyle`:

```
navigationOptions = {
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
);
```

For status bar, see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html

Comment: The `navigationOptions`? Just replace your current one with this (add in the `static` keyword). Do you need a custom `header` component? What changes are you making to it?

Comment: I just want to add a color to the bar along with the current attributes.

Comment: No it doesn't give any color at all. It changes to white and all the other attributes will go.

Comment: Changed it using custom header. Thanks!

Comment: The link is dead, should be: https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
static navigationOptions = () => ({
    title: 'Home',
    headerTintColor: '#cccccc',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#000',
    },      
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below parameter to set the status bar color:

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor='blue' barStyle='light-content' />
```

Comment: I need to know about Action bar also along with status bar.